# Удалить массивы с определенным значением из массива

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив содержащий массивы с пустыми строками.мне нужно удалить все массивы с пустыми строками и оставить только те,которые содержат текст. Правильно ли я понимаю,что лучше сначала делать for each а затем filter? Таким путем не получается
пример:

```js
let array = [
   ["Text1"],
   [""],
   ["Text"],
   ["Text2"],
   [""],
   ["Text 4"],
   [""],
   ["Text5"],
   [""],
   ["Text6"],
   [""],
   ["Text7"],
   [""],
   ["Text8"],
   [""]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let array = [
   ["Text1"],
   [""],
   ["Text"],
   ["Text2"],
   [""],
   ["Text 4"],
   [""],
   ["Text5"],
   [""],
   ["Text6"],
   [""],
   ["Text7"],
   [""],
   ["Text8"],
   [""]
]
 
array = array.filter(el => el != "")
console.log(array)
```